# Can anyone explain the use of ConcurrentLinkedList with example?

Tags: multithreading

1.If we have two threads using ConcurrentLinkedQueue, where one thread inserts data to the list and the other thread accesses data at same time.

Examples of event sequences are shown below.

Eg1

```
Puts1   
consume1  
Puts2    
consumes
Puts3
Consume3
```

Eg2

```
puts1
puts2
puts3
consume1
consume2
consume3
```

2.Should the operation between the two threads be synchronized? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ConcurrentLinkedList` is "thread-safe".  That means, any given instance of the class will not do anything surprising when you call its methods from different threads.

It does *not* mean that *your program* will do what you expect when you have multiple threads using the same list object at the same time.

Thread safety is not composeable:  That is to say, building a program entirely out of thread-safe classes will not make the program itself thread-safe.  The program is only thread safe if its various threads cooperate with one another, and do not interfere with one another.